# Infinitive vs conjugated verb

Tags: verbs, infinitive

Is there any difference between the two sentences below?

- Non so se girare a sinistra o a destra.
- Non so se giro a sinistra o a destra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one implies that the action of turning will happen in the future (near or far).
The second one is something you say when the action of turning is running now.
"Non so se giro a sinistra o a destra" means I don't know if now I'm turning left or right.
"Non so se girare a sinistra o a destra" means "I don't know whether to turn left or right"
(either in the near or in the far future).

Comment: Is "Non so se girare a sinistra o a destra" a sentence by itself in Italian? I know that "I don't know whether to turn left or right" is a valid sentence in English , but in the equivalent sentence in other Romance languages the speaker would have to complement with something like "is the best option" or use "Non so se giro a sinistra o a destra" instead.

Comment: both of them are italian, but the meaning differ. In the context you mentioned in the upper comment, the best solution (the only valid in my honest opinion) is to use  "Non so se girare a sinistra o a destra" because it imply that I'm deciding which option is better.